# Simplifying and rearranging a system of equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have derived a set of equations of motion and now want to rearrange and simply them, but I am not sure which command I should use.

For example, I have:

```
d F_1 + e F_2 == M a; 
F_1 == m + n; 
F_2 == f + g; 
m == K + L;
```

Now I want to eliminate `F_1`, `F_2`, and `m`, since they are redundant. I tried `Eliminate`, but it gave me weird results when I had more than one set of such equations. What is the best command I should use to rearrange and simplify these equations?

Answer (score 1):

```
eqns = {d F1 + e F2 == M a, F1 == m + n, F2 == f + g, m == k + l};
Eliminate[eqns, {F1, F2, m}]
```

> -e g - d k - d l + a M - d n == e f

Note: `F_1` and `F_2` are not appropriate variable names in Mathematica. (See [Blank (_)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) in the docs.)